# Combination of Soccer Players

Tags: combinatorics

"A group of 30 students try out for a soccer team, which consist of 11 players. In how many ways can you select a team where there is a captain and an assistant captain?"

I feel like there will be two main steps to this problem, but I am not sure what...

Comment: Choose a captain, choose an assistant from the remaining and choose 9 other players from the remaining.

Answer (score 1):

$30$ options for the captain and $29$ options for the co-captain.

After this there are $28$ candidates and we must choose $9$, we can do this in $\binom{28}{9}=\frac{28!}{19!9!}=6906900$

The final answer is then $30\cdot29\cdot\binom{28}{9}=6009003000$

You may also want to revise what a binomial coefficient is.